# DB2: JSON_OBJECT with CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, json, db2, case

If I use a CASE WHEN statement before a JSON_OBJECT, I do not get a correct JSON result. The object is somehow encoded to a string

Example: The code:

...

), json_object(
'uomId' value 'PL',
'ratio' value :mgve,
'baseUomFlag' value 'false',
'pickUomFlag' value 'false',
'putawayUomFlag' value 'false',
'storageCluster' value 'AB_ITEM'
), case when :vpe = 'TE' and :mgvpe > 1 THEN json_object(
'uomId' value 'TE',
'ratio' value :mgvpe,
'baseUomFlag' value 'false',
'pickUomFlag' value 'false',
'putawayUomFlag' value 'false',
'storageCluster' value 'AB_ITEM') END

...

leads to:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please tag the correct Db2-flavour for your SERVER (db2-zos, db2-400, db2-luw).   Please edit your question to show the exact VERSION and FIXPACK of your Db2-server.

Comment: If this is for LUW, you can use https://dbfiddle.uk/6pjm1B_y to create a scenario. I tried (11.5.8) db2 "describe values case when 'TE' = 'TE' and 2 > 1 THEN json_object(
'uomId' value 'TE', 'baseUomFlag' value 'false') END" and it returns a CLOB as expected